# cv::Mat copy constructor doesn't copy underlying data

Tags: c++, opencv

This code snippet:

```
double a[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
cv::Mat m{cv::Mat{2, 2, CV_64F, &a[0]}};
a[1] = 9;
std::cout << m.at<double>(1)
```

prints `9`, despite page 76 of "Learning OpenCV 3" book placing `cv::Mat(const Mat& mat)` copy constructor in "Table 4-2. cv::Mat constructors that copy data from other cv::Mats". Am I reading it wrong?

I know that `cv::Mat m{cv::Mat{2, 2, CV_64F, &a[0]}.clone()};` will make a copy of `a` and print `2`.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e) of the copy constructor. "No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. So, when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the corresponding elements of m . If you want to have an independent copy of the sub-array, use `Mat::clone()`."

Comment: Not sure what the author of the book wanted to say, but by default copies and assignment are shallow (`Mat` behaves much like a `shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you are using is documented here: [OpenCV Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a).

When you create your lvalue m

`cv::Mat m{cv::Mat{2, 2, CV_64F, &a[0]}};`

you invoke the copy constructor of cv::Mat, but the instance that is copied (your rvalue temporary) never actually owned the data in the first place; it just holds a pointer.
Thus your new matrix `m` will hold the same pointer to `a`.

TL;DR you are using a non-allocating constructor for your temporary.

Comment: I know, but my point is that "Learning OpenCV 3" book suggests copy constructor is making the copy of underlying data. The documentation you linked, doesn't elaborate that point.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding on either your side or the author's side here. When talking about copy constructors in the context of `cv::Mat`, it generally means that the members of that class are copied, not the underlying data. And indeed this is what happens in your case: the pointer to the data is copied.

Comment: Perhaps an erratum is in order. The table I mentioned reads `constructors that copy data` vs. documentation `No data is copied by these constructors`.